# Unable to get the list of followers in twitter using Fabric Android

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Fabric sdk for Twitter. In this I am able to make login request as it's described in its document. Now I wan't to get list of follower of logged in user and show in a listview.I have tried many links but these links not work for me

[How to get list of followers using Twitter Fabric Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106290/how-to-get-list-of-followers-using-twitter-fabric-android)

[Can't get List of followers in Twitter using Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759374/cant-get-list-of-followers-in-twitter-using-fabric)

then i tried this code but still my app crashed everytime when i run it.

```
class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient 
    {
        public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) 
    {
            super(session);
        }

        public CustomService getCustomService() {
            return getService(CustomService.class);
        }

        interface CustomService {
            @GET("/1.1/followers/list.json")
            Call<User> show(@Query("user_id") Long userId, @Query("screen_name") String
                        var, @Query("skip_status") Boolean var1, @Query("include_user_entities") Boolean var2, @Query("count") Integer var3, Callback < Followers > cb);
        }
    }
```

Called like this:

```
new MyTwitterApiClient(session).getCustomService().show(userID, null, true, true, 100, new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> result) {
                LogUtils.LOGI("Get success",result.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
```

By this method I am not able to get followers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use updated version **Retrofit2**.

Write following code in your gradle file:-

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'`

Try Following code :

Interface:

```
public interface TwitterFollowersService {
    /**
     * This method id used to get the List of TWITTER FOLLOWERS.
     *
     * @param userId Get UserId after login and pass it here
     * @param var    Send Current user screen name
     * @param var1   Weather to skip status accept TRUE/FALSE
     * @param var2   Weather to include Entities accept TRUE/FALSE
     * @param var3   Count to get number of response
     * @return Call object of type FOLLOWERS.
     */
    @GET("/1.1/followers/list.json")
    Call<Response> show(@Query("user_id") Long userId, @Query("screen_name") String
            var, @Query("skip_status") Boolean var1, @Query("include_user_entities") Boolean
                                var2, @Query("count") Integer var3);

}
```

use this code in you class/Activity:

```
private Callback<TwitterSession> authorizeCallback = new Callback<TwitterSession>() {

    @Override
    public void success(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result<TwitterSession> result) {

        TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

        if (isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            if (session != null) {
                TwitterApiServices apiclients = new TwitterApiServices(session);
                Call<Response> call = apiclients.getCustomService().show(result.data.getUserId(), result.data.getUserName(), true, false, 100);
                call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                        if (response.body().getUsers().size() > 0) {

                            ArrayList<TwitterFollowersList> twitterFollowersList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getUsers().size(); i++) {

                                TwitterFollowersList twitterFollowers = new TwitterFollowersList();

                                twitterFollowers.setId(response.body().getUsers().get(i).getId());
                                twitterFollowers.setName(response.body().getUsers().get(i).getName());
                                twitterFollowers.setProfile_image_url(response.body().getUsers().get(i).getProfile_image_url());

                                Log.d("TwitterFollowers", "ID: " + response.body().getUsers().get(i).getId() + "  Name: " + response.body().getUsers().get(i).getName() + "  ProfileImageURL: " + response.body().getUsers().get(i).getProfile_image_url());

                                twitterFollowersList.add(twitterFollowers);
                            }
                            //Upload twitter folowers to server.
                            uploadUserTwitterContacts(twitterFollowersList);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                        showToast(this, "Unable to get response. Try Again!!");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                showToast(this, getResources().getString(R.string.server_error));

            }
        } else {
            showToast(this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
        showToast(this, getResources().getString(R.string.server_error));

    }
};
```

Use these following model classes as a **response**, and make their getter setter:

1)

```
 public class Response {

        @SerializedName("users")
        private List<Users> users;
        private String next_cursor;
        private String previous_cursor_str;
        private String previous_cursor;
        private String next_cursor_str;
    }
```

2)

```
public class Users {
    private String location;

    private String default_profile;

    private String profile_background_tile;

    private String statuses_count;

    private String live_following;

    private String lang;

    private String profile_link_color;

    private String profile_banner_url;

    private String id;

    private String following;

    private String muting;

    //private String protected;

    private String favourites_count;

    private String profile_text_color;

    private String description;

    private String verified;

    private String contributors_enabled;

    private String profile_sidebar_border_color;

    private String name;

    private String profile_background_color;

    private String created_at;

    private String is_translation_enabled;

    private String default_profile_image;

    private String followers_count;

    private String has_extended_profile;

    private String profile_image_url_https;

    private String geo_enabled;

    //private Status status;

    private String profile_background_image_url;

    private String profile_background_image_url_https;

    private String follow_request_sent;

    //private Entities entities;

    private String url;

    private String utc_offset;

    private String time_zone;

    private String blocking;

    private String notifications;

    private String profile_use_background_image;

    private String friends_count;

    private String blocked_by;

    private String profile_sidebar_fill_color;

    private String screen_name;

    private String id_str;

    private String profile_image_url;

    private String listed_count;

    private String is_translator;
}
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: :)
Also give up to this accepted answer :p  ,,


howz u @RahulAbrol